# Str + F in Java in a Text File

Tags: java, web-services, substring

I am doing some Java programming in `Android Studio`.

I have a really big file (which I get via webservice call, see picture), which I need to first store in a string variable and then I need to find certain values (in that big ass string) and store them in a 'Sub'-String. Let's have a look at the file first:

[image]

Step one would be to save the file in a big string variable. Then Step 2:
I would like to do a search with a if-statement and save the results in 'sub strings'. So for example:

```
String available_flag;
String title;
String long_description;

if (sku==395221) then 
{
available_flag = "1";
title = "Judith Williams Jeans &quot;Milano&quot;, mit Schmucknieten";
long_description= ">&lt;h2&gt;Basic mit dem gewissen Etwas&lt;/h2&gt; &lt;p&gt;Mit dieser Judith Williams Jeans schenken";
}
```

Do you guys understand my problem? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: what is the question actually??

Comment: Since the string is XML, you should use an XML Parser.

Comment: I need Strings which contain values of the file (see pseudo code example). I need to know how to solve this ?